# Why only the lastinsertid being inserted in db on foreach?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a foreach loop which assigns the variable $thread_id to the value  of  lastInsertId() .

The $thread_id then gets inserted to the applicants table.

The problem that I am having is that it inserts the last value that is in the loop to all the rows. But the weird thing is when I output the $thread_id to the console, it shows a different value each time the loop iterates.

as an example, When I output $thread_id in the console it shows this

1,2,3,4,5,6

then when i view all the rows in the applicants table i see this

6
6
6
6
6
6

I am really confused on why this is happening. If anyone could help me out with this issue I would really appreciate it. Below is my code.

```
$msg_table_insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO msg_messages (
                  sender_id,recipient_id,msg ) VALUES (
                  :sender_id, :recipient_id, :msg)");

        $applicant_update_query = $db->prepare("UPDATE applicants SET thread_id = :thread_id ");


foreach($applicants as $applicant) 
{

 if($thread_id == 0){
    $msg_table_insert->execute(
        [':sender_id'   => $applicant_array[SENDER_ID], 
        ':recipient_id' => $applicant_array[RECIPIENT_ID], 
        ':msg'          => $templated_msg_body]);

    $thread_id = $db->lastInsertId();

    $applicant_update_query->execute([':thread_id' =>  $thread_id ]);
}
    }
```

Comment: what is the variable `$applicant_update_query` ?

Comment: And how is `$applicant_array` related to the values you're iterating over, which have totally different names ?

Comment: What is the UPDATE query you are running, can you post the prepare statement for `$applicant_update_query`?

Comment: `$applicant` never appears inside the foreach loop

Comment: sorry I just added the update query

Comment: @adeneo . The $applicant array is just info about the applicant but I didn't include that code to make things more simple. it is not relevant to the query

Comment: you update ALL applicants with the thread_id so while you update with  1,2,3,4,5,6  at the end all your going to see is **6**

Comment: @Dagon oh wow... I can't believe I didn't notice that...know I see whats happening. I need to add a where clause. Thank you so much for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Somebody solved your mistake but beyond that, why? you update a field in a row with lastinsertId(); after just insert.  You should define a field for that, so that mysql does it for you automatically.